# How to load & execute Python script in Hue?

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, hue

I'm a new Hadoop user and am attempting to run Python script via the Hue interface.

After some searching I've found a solution in the cloudera forum:

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Web-UI-Hue-Beeswax/How-to-run-Python-script-in-Hue-through-oozie/m-p/61455

where the poster stated "The solution was to put the python script in Hue -> Query -> Editor -> Spark in the Libs field with the full path of the python script example: Libs:  /user/userxyz/myscript.py and run the query. Clicking the job_xxxxx link will show if the script ran successfully or not."

However, I can't figure out how to load & then execute my Python script in the Hadoop distributed file system. The Hue interface doesn't seem to have an HDFS feature that displays my root & allows file uploads. Do I load my Python script as a text file from my desktop or is there an editor in Hue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python scripts probably should be run from the Oozie Script Task by `python script.py`, and attaching the HDFS file reference to the workflow task.

If you don't have Spark code, then you shoudn't be using Spark Notebook Editor for it.

> is there an editor in Hue?

There is, if you click any document in the File Browser, but this will download the file to the Hue server filesystem, then re-upload, so it's better to edit and upload directly on your own.

> Hue interface doesn't seem to have an HDFS feature that displays my root & allows file uploads

There is a configuration setting in the INI that allows file uploads [which is true by default](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/desktop/conf.dist/hue.ini#L1268-L1269). If you have the File Browser completely disabled, or maybe even an old version of Hue, it probably isn't there.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! This is helpful. I got in touch with my company's data mgmt folks & they recommended using PySpark to process Python script on Hadoop.

Comment: Yes, you can use PySpark, sure. But there are other Python libraries too for using Hive, HBase, or HDFS

Answer (score 1):

You can write a python script into HUE and save the file as myScript.py.
In order to use python and distributed file system you have to install pySpark for example. 
Then you can go to Oozie editor and choose Spark Action. At the `Jar/py name` field you have to give the **myScript.py**. As **ARGUMENTS** you should give the path where the pySpark (python Api) is installed. Also at the **FILES** you have to give the path where the myScript.py is saved.